# LocalStorage.setItem not called on initial state setting; called with previous value on subsequent form submissions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a simple todo list to start learning React.  I have the following file.

The issue I'm running into is during the form submission callback `handleSubmit`.  The first time I enter a new todo, lets say with the value `hello`, `todos` is updated and the view redraws, however, localStorage isn't updated and the input isnt cleared by the call to `setTodoEntry`.

On a subsequent form submission, say with the value `world`, `todos` is updated and the view redraws, however this time localStorage is updated with the value from the previous call (`todoEntry === 'hello'`).  The input still isnt cleared by `setTodoEntry`.  On subsequent form submissions localStorage is always one "step" behind, and the input never clears.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Todo from './components/todo'
import { TextField, Button } from '@mui/material';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

function App() {
  let myStoredTodos = localStorage.getItem('todos');
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(myStoredTodos ? JSON.parse(myStoredTodos) : []); 
  const [todoEntry, setTodoEntry] = useState('');
  
  function handleTodoEntry(event) {
    setTodoEntry(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!todoEntry) return;
    setTodos([ { id: nanoid(), checked: false, value: todoEntry }, ...todos ])
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    setTodoEntry('');
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{`//TODO`}</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField variant="standard" onChange={(event) => handleTodoEntry(event)} />
        <Button id="add-button" type="submit" variant="contained" disabled={!todoEntry.length}>Add</Button>
      </form>
      
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            <Todo checked={todo.checked} value={todo.value} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state updates are asynchronous and the value of `todos` is essentially fixed inside the closure. You can instead get the new value after the next render inside an effect.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
}, [todos]);
```

Also, to keep the `TextField` controlled, set its value to `todoEntry`. (See the [Uncontrolled vs Controlled](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled) section of the MUI Text Field documentation.)

```
<TextField variant="standard" value={todoEntry} onChange={(event) => handleTodoEntry(event)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

setTodos will schedule the update but doesn't immediately apply it. When you call `localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));` after setTodos, the todos array hasn't been updated yet.

Use the previous state in the SetTodos function:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!todoEntry) return;
  setTodos((prevTodos) => {
    const newTodos = [{ id: nanoid(), checked: false, value: todoEntry }, ...prevTodos];
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(newTodos));
    return newTodos;
  });
  setTodoEntry('');
}
```

If the input is not cleared, make sure you bind the todoEntry state to the TextField's value:

`<TextField variant="standard" value={todoEntry} onChange={(event) => handleTodoEntry(event)} />`